# Which year saw the highest and lowest no of countries participating in olympics?

Tags: mysql, sql, kaggle

I'm new to SQL & practicing OLYMPICS dataset on kaggle & unable to query out the result in single row. The question mark is where I am stuck

```
select games, count(DISTINCT r.region) AS a, count(DISTINCT r.region) AS b
from oly
JOIN regions r 
  ON oly.noc = r.noc
group by games
order by a ASC
LIMIT 1
```

?????

```
select games, count(DISTINCT r.region) AS B
from oly
JOIN regions r 
  ON oly.noc = r.noc
GROUP BY games
ORDER BY  B desc
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: [1]: https://www.kaggle.com/heesoo37/120-years-of-olympic-history-athletes-and-results (DATASET)
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6llUh.jpg  (SAMPLE DATA)

Comment: A question here should be self-contained. I.e. include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As you only have 1 Row per subquery you can use CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT
    a1.games,a1.a,a1.b,b1.games,b1.B
FROM
(select games, count(DISTINCT r.region) AS a, count(DISTINCT r.region) AS b  from oly
JOIN regions r 
ON oly.noc = r.noc
group by games
order by a ASC LIMIT 1) a1
CROSS JOIN 
(select games, count(DISTINCT r.region) AS B  from oly
JOIN regions r 
ON oly.noc = r.noc
GROUP BY games
ORDER BY  B desc LIMIT 1 ) b1
```